# Expected singleton odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

After enter 2 and more new row in tree view and click on save get error

```
  raise ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % self)
ValueError: Expected singleton: my.model(2116, 2117)
```

My source code:

```
@api.depends('start', 'finish','stop')
def total_fun(self): 
    time1 = datetime.strptime(self.start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    time2 = datetime.strptime(self.finish, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    self.total = round(((time2 - time1).seconds / float(60*60) - self.stop))
```

Comment: I hope it will help you in future. https://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.in/2017/02/valueerror-expected-singleton-in-odoo.html

Comment: Just as a little hint: Use Odoo's `fields.Date` and `fields.Datetime` functions for converting date/datetimes. There are `from_string()` and `to_string()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error message says -> `expected singleton` this means: you are using recordset instead of record.

To fix this use

```
for rec in self:
```

in the begining of function, and then use `rec` instead of `self`

Comment: Tnx, also before @ api.depends I'm add @ api.one

Comment: if you've added `@api.one` then you don't need the for loop anymore, because odoo will loop for itself through the whole recordset. So `self` will always be a singleton.

Comment: @CZoellner In my example not working without api.one

Comment: Your source code example with an added `@api.one` should run without problems.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the error message `Expected singleton: my.model(2116, 2117)`

By default in odoo the self is always a recordSet (means it can contain more then one record.) so when you do `self.getSomeField` here odoo will be confused wich record you want to get the value from.

if you don't tell odoo that make sure that the self will always contain one record when you acces an attribute if the recordSet contains more than one record this error is raised.

Now how to tell odoo make sure there is always one record is by adding `@api.one` decorator to the method. but is not recommended because odoo in your case there is two record so he will loop and call the method for each record and pass a recordSet that have only that record. imagine that you execute a search or any communication with database.

so don't use `@api.one` only if you are sure of what you are doing because you can make 10000 method call and interact with database.

like this example using `@api.one`:

```
   # every call to this method you will execute a search.
   self.env['some.model'].search([('m2o_id' , '=', self.id)]
```

you can do this before the loop:

```
  # one query for all record with one call to the method
  result = self.env['some.model'].search([('m2o_id' , 'in', self.ids)]
  for rec in self:
      # use result here 
  # or here ..
```